# Configuring LDAP authentication with Silex and Symfony 3

Tags: php, ldap, silex, symfony

I am trying to configure LDAP authentication in my Silex (1.3.5) application using the LDAP component provided by Symfony (3.0.1).
Here is my current configuration:

```php
$app['ldap'] = function () {
    return new Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient('ldap.example.com');
};

$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), [
    'security.providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'ldap' => [
                'service' => 'ldap',
                'base_dn' => 'dc=example,dc=com',
                'search_dn' => 'CN={username},OU=DEV,DC=example,DC=com',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'security.firewalls' => [
        'stats' => [
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'http' => true,
            'stateless' => true,
            'http_basic_ldap' => [
                'service' => 'ldap',
                'dn_string' => '{username}@example.com',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

But with the above configuration, I get the following exception:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'The "provider" authentication entry is not registered.' in /var/www/my-site/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php:243 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/my-site/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php(126): Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider->Silex\Provider{closure}(Object(Silex\Application)) #1 /var/www/my-site/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php(83): Silex\Application::{closure}(Object(Silex\Application)) #2 /var/www/my-site/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php(150): Pimple->offsetGet('security.firewa...') #3 /var/www/my-site/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php(126): Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider->Silex\Provider{closure}(Object(Silex\Application)) #4 /var/www/my-site/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php(83): Silex\Application::{closure}(Object(Silex\Application)) #5 /var/www/my-site/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php(584): in /var/www/my-site/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/SecurityServiceProvider.php on line 243

Is there something to do to make the LDAP component work with Silex? Or am I missing some configuration? I didn't find any documentation for that component...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silex security configuration works otherwise.
User providers are defined as `$app['security.user_provider.%firewall_name%']`, not as `provider` key in firewall config.

Try to change your config to:

```
$app['ldap'] = $app->share(function() {
    return new Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient('ldap.example.com');
});

$app['security.user_provider.stats'] = $app->share(function($app) {
    return new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider(
        $app['ldap'],
        'dc=example,dc=com',
        null,
        null,
        ['ROLE_USER'],
        'CN'
    );
});

$app['security.authentication_provider.stats.dao'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\LdapBindAuthenticationProvider(
        $app['security.user_provider.stats'],
        $app['security.user_checker'],
        'stats',
        $app['ldap'],
        'CN={username},OU=DEV,DC=example,DC=com',
        $app['security.hide_user_not_found']
    );
};

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
    'security.firewalls' => [
        'stats' => [
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'http' => true,
            'stateless' => true,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

**UPDATE:** Or better use this decision [Symfony LDAP auth bind with username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719259/symfony-ldap-auth-bind-with-username-and-password/42736898). I think that it is better.