# Symfony LDAP auth bind with username and password

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I am trying to get LDAP authentication working for Symfony firewall but am having trouble. The main issue seems to stem from the Symfony `LdapUserProvider` - it does not take the user supplied username and password when trying `ldap_bind()`.

So, I have this as my firewall config:

```
$app->register(new SilexProvider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
    'security.firewalls' => [
        'secured' => [
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'http' => true,
            'users' => new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider(
                \Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap::create('ext_ldap', [
                    'connection_string' => 'ldap://MY_LDAP_DOMAIN',
                ]),
                'dc=MY_DC_1,dc=MY_DC_2',
                'uid={username},cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=MY_DC_1,dc=MY_DC_2'
            ),
        ],
    ],
]);
```

But my `{username}` part is not replaced by the user supplied username when the `ldap_bind` method is called. So, the `dn` string passed to `ldap_bind` is literally `uid={username},cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=MY_DC_1,dc=MY_DC_2` - the username isn't replaced.

If I look through the code though this is expected, as `LdapUserProvider->loadUserByUsername()` calls `bind` before doing any string replacements. The other problem is that it does not know the user supplied password until much later, so the `bind` call again doesn't have the user supplied password.

How can I set this up so that it will replace my `dn` and password appropriately? If I use these 2 basic lines (where `$data` is an array of a valid user):

```
$ldap = ldap_connect('MY_LDAP_DOMAIN');
$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, 'uid=' . $data['username'] . ',cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=MY_DC_1,dc=MY_DC_2', $data['password']);
```

Then it binds perfectly. How can I translate those 2 lines into a situation that Symfony firewall understands?

Answer (score 3):

You have **2** main issues in the existing code:

1. Symfony's `LdapUserProvider` component by default uses Active Directory (Windows) schema: `sAMAccountName={username}` instead of Open LDAP's `uid={username}`
2. You're using built-in `http` security firewall, which by default uses `DaoAuthenticationProvider` authentication provider . In case of LDAP authentication, you need to use `LdapBindAuthenticationProvider` instead.

**The first issue** can be solved by passing user identifier key to `LdapUserProvider`:

```
$app['ldap.users'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new LdapUserProvider(
        // your LDAP adapter
        $app['ldap'],
        // base DN
        'dc=example,dc=com',
        // you don't need search DN
        null,
        // you don't need search password
        null,
        // list of default roles, can be empty array
        ['ROLE_USER'],
        // user identifier key for LDAP
        // this identitfer must be set explicitly
        'uid'
    );
};
```

Notice 3rd and 4th parameters can be `null`, because they will never be used: `LdapBindAuthenticationProvider` will be invoked first, so LDAP connection already will be bound.

**The second issue** requires a little bit of coding. Symfony has built-in `http_basic_ldap` authentication provider which perfectly suits your requirements. Unfortunately, Silex doesn't have one, so you need to do it on your own. Use Silex documentation for reference: [Defining a custom Authentication Provider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-authentication-provider)

Here is my example of `form_login_ldap` implementation for Silex.
Registering all LDAP-related services:

```
$app // register other services
    ->register(new LdapServiceProvider())
    ->register(new LdapUsersServiceProvider())
    ->register(new LdapSecurityServiceProvider())
    ->register(new \Silex\Provider\SecurityServiceProvider(), [
        'security.firewalls' => [
            'login' => [
                'pattern' => '^/login$',
            ],
            'secured' => [
                'pattern' => '^.*$',
                'form_login_ldap' => [
                    'login_path' => 'login',
                    'check_path' => 'login_check',
                    'default_target_path' => 'backoffice',
                ],
                'users' => $this['ldap.users'],
            ],
        ],
    ])
;
```

Service Provider for LDAP Adapter

```
use Pimple\Container;
use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap;

class LdapServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app)
    {
        $app['ldap'] = function () {
            return Ldap::create('ext_ldap', [
                'connection_string' => 'ldap.example.com',
            ]);
        };
    }
}
```

Service Provider for LDAP Users

```
use Pimple\Container;
use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\LdapUserProvider;

class LdapUsersServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app)
    {
        $app['ldap.users'] = function () use ($app) {
            return new LdapUserProvider(
                $app['ldap'],
                'dc=example,dc=com',
                null,
                null,
                ['ROLE_USER'],
                'uid'
            );
        };
    }
}
```

Service Provider for Security Authentication Listener Factory for LDAP Form (the most interesting part for you)

```
use Pimple\Container;
use Pimple\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\LdapBindAuthenticationProvider;

class LdapSecurityServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app)
    {
        $app['security.authentication_listener.factory.form_login_ldap'] = $app->protect(function ($name, $options) use ($app) {
            // define the authentication provider object
            $app['security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.form_login_ldap'] = function () use ($app, $name) {
                return new LdapBindAuthenticationProvider(
                    $app['security.user_provider.'.$name],
                    $app['security.user_checker'],
                    $name,
                    $app['ldap'],
                    'uid={username},dc=example,dc=com',
                    $app['security.hide_user_not_found']
                );
            };

            // define the authentication listener object
            $app['security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.form_login_ldap'] = $app['security.authentication_listener.form._proto']($name, $options);

            // define the entry point object
            $app[$entryPoint = 'security.entry_point.'.$name.'.form_login_ldap'] = $app['security.entry_point.form._proto']($name, array());

            return array(
                // the authentication provider id
                'security.authentication_provider.'.$name.'.form_login_ldap',
                // the authentication listener id
                'security.authentication_listener.'.$name.'.form_login_ldap',
                // the entry point id
                $entryPoint,
                // the position of the listener in the stack
                'form'
            );
        });
    }
}
```